# Why does copper become more thermally conductive the colder it gets until 10 Kelvin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity

I was wondering about superconductors and how much more conductive copper is when it is super-cooled. I mistakenly stumbled upon [this page](https://www.efunda.com/materials/elements/TC_Table.cfm?Element_ID=Cu) that describes copper's **thermal** conductivity with no external references. It says that copper gets more conductive the colder it gets until about 10 Kelvin, then it interestingly becomes *less* conductive, which I found interesting.

So I looked for some more credible information to verify this data and I found [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjnouuXuevnAhUNGDQIHWMQD9sQFjAOegQICRAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.publish.csiro.au%2Fph%2Fpdf%2FPH530397&usg=AOvVaw1QCYR5yNF2jRXQXszos1QB) which supported that data, but I had a hard time understanding the text.

Can anyone explain why copper becomes more thermally conductive the colder it gets, but then starts to lose its conductivity below 10 Kelvin?

Comment: That is the _thermal_ conductivity of copper. I know that electrical conductivity is sample dependent. Magnetic impurities may give an increase at low $T$ (Kondo effect).

Comment: @Pieter thanks for catching that. That changes the question a bit, but I still would like to know the answer nonetheless. I will make an edit to clarify thermal conductivity

Comment: Well, why shouldn’t it? Many things are not monotonic across broad temperature ranges.

Comment: @Jon Custer, and each one of those has a different reason for that behavior. Doesn't mean we shouldn't try to explain the physics at play here. There is very systematic behavior here for highly pure metals that can't be considered a weird accident https://hydrogen.wsu.edu/2018/03/08/common-cryogenic-copper-confusions/

Comment: Here is the abstract of a more recent paper (1990) on very pure silver (Residual Resistivity Ratio = 1900) where things were still called "unexplained": https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-8984/2/22/007/meta